# How to get the default List Style in Swift UI without Using List?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'am trying to have the native List Styles (The background, padding and dividers) without using an actual List, reason is it will be part of a ScrollView, and I cannot nest a List in a Scroll view. Is there a way to do it without having to make create the styles myself?

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve

[image: Desired layout]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why would you put a `List` in a `ScrollView`? What kind of UI are you trying to do? The screenshot you showed just looks like a normal `List` to me.

Comment: That looks like a `List` 100% I don't see where the ScrollView comes into play

Comment: This is just part of the Page, the page has also a picture and some other stuff on top, and I don't want it to be part of the list.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm trying to have the default visual "styles" of when I use List but without using "List"

Comment: You'll have to make it all custom then

Comment: "the page has also a picture and some other stuff on top" Show "some other stuff" in your picture then. This is definitely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Just ended up making it all custom..

Answer (score 1):

I have used some thing similar you can try if it works for you

1. Create a Menu Data Set
2. Create Cell View
3. Create Scroll Outer view (you can also Include Scroll View)

private let boxMenuList: [MenuListModel] = [.init(icon: Icons.chatRounded, title: "My chats"),
.init(icon: Icons.saveMenu, title: "Saved"),]

```
func verticalMenuCellView(icon: String, title: String) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            Image(icon)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
            
            Text(title)
                .setFont(type: .semiBold)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "chevron.forward")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.5))
        }
        .padding()
    }

func MenuBoxView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(boxMenuList, id: \.title) { menu in
                verticalMenuCellView(icon: menu.icon, title: menu.title)
            }
        }
        .background(.ultraThinMatirial)
        .cornerRadius(24)
        .padding(.horizontal, 32)
    }
```

but you might loss feature of base list you example

swipe to delete
creating sections with pinned header, etc
[image]